# gmail reply to forwarded mails fail

Tags: redirection, postfix

I have a mail server postfix, and for an account i forward mails to gmail.

user1@domaine1.com => user@gmail.com

The forward works, but in gmail when I try to reply to forwarded mails I have a fail :

Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

```
 guillaume@domaine.com
```

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the relay smtp.domaine1.com by smtp.domaine1.com. [IP].

The error that the other server returned was:
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure (SMTP AUTH failed with the remote server)

why it try to send mails to smtp.domaine1.com for user guillaume@domaine.com

Sincerely

Comment: I found that the problems come from SASL Auth on my server :
warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed

But now I don't know with SASL works on my server for first instance, perhaps no for the second postfix instance.

Answer (score 0):

I found where is my mistake. When I create my second postfix instance i forgive to create the sasl/smtpd.conf fite pour sasl configuration of the second instance.

Now It's works I can reply with gmail with my smtp.